# So sockets generated by socketpair() are availble across different processes?

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor

As we know `fd`(file descriptor,an `int` to be exact) is per process,that is,the same file opened in different processes may have different `fd`.

And I thought so should be for sockets.

But when reading nginx source code I found it's using sockets to communicate between processes:

```
    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, ngx_processes[s].channel) == -1)
    {
        ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ALERT, cycle->log, ngx_errno,
                      "socketpair() failed while spawning \"%s\"", name);
        return NGX_INVALID_PID;
    }
```

Here `ngx_processes[s].channel[0]` is sent to other process.

But as I said `fd` is per process,how can it ensure that the same `int` will point to the same socket?

**UPDATE**

Why question is now how this works(it's the same way that nginx uses)?

http://swtch.com/usr/local/plan9/src/lib9/sendfd.c

Comment: Your code snippet does not include anything about "sending the fd to another process" so it's impossible to answer. The answer depends on whether you'e forking or using some hack for transferring fds between processes.

Comment: @R.. ,yes the code above doesn't include logic to sent `socketfd` to other process. Do you mean that if using forking,the same fd can be used among processes?

Comment: Therefore your question really can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: If you simply created the socket with `socketpair` then called `fork`, then of course the file descriptor numbers (like basically *everything* except the pid and threads) will be the same in the child process. This is the normal way `socketpair` and `pipe` are used.

Comment: I don't know why @nos deleted his answer,but his link is using the same way to send `fd`,which I don't understand how it works: http://swtch.com/usr/local/plan9/src/lib9/sendfd.c

Comment: @R.. ,the `socketfd` is **sent** to already `fork()`ed childs,I do understand all variables will be the same in child right after calling `fork()`.

Comment: @compile-fan By what mechanism is the fd "sent" ?

Comment: @cnicutar ,I don't know how it works,see http://swtch.com/usr/local/plan9/src/lib9/sendfd.c

Comment: @compile-fan What's Plan 9 got to do with `nginx` ? What are you smoking ?

Comment: @cnicutar: The code compile-fan linked is actually the way to send an fd over a unix socket, which is fairly standard

Comment: @Hasturkun So you're saying a socket is used to send a socket from a socket pair ? Does that *really* make sense ?

Comment: @compile-fan I deleted the answer because the other comments/answers are probably right, that the fd in this case is shared by forking and not the unix way of sending an fd to an existing process. You should dig through the ngnix source code more to find actually how the descriptor is shared among processes, as the current code snippet just shows creating a socket-pair, not the actually sharing of a file descriptor.

Comment: @cnicutar: Actually, I just looked at the source, and it seems to do exactly that. sending the socket pair (for a channel belonging to a new subprocess) to each of its subprocesses in turn. the pair for each process is inherited by the fork though. follow [`ngx_start_worker_processes`](http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.c#L332) if you're interested

Comment: @Hasturkun I just read `ngx_write_channel`. I stand corrected.

Comment: @nos ,nginx is using exactly the same way as your link to send `fd`,nothing to do with `fork`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nginx uses unix domain sockets ancillary messages (specifically, the `SCM_RIGHTS` message, see  the [man page for the unix protocol](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) for more information on this) to pass file descriptors around.

When you receive an `SCM_RIGHTS` message, the kernel basically gives you a duplicate (as in `dup`) file descriptor, valid in the receiving process. This fd may or may not have the same number, which matters very little as the receiving side should use the contents of the message  and not some prior knowledge.